# Visual Studio 2015 Nuget Restore Problems for Version 1.0.3 of Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Tags: tfs, json.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a solution which was working with Visual Studio 2015 Community in a machine.  That machine was crashed and I can not access the source codes over there any more.

However the source codes were checked into TFS.  After I got new machine, I got all latest source codes from TFS.

The issue is that this solution in new machine has a lot of compile errors.

Visual Studio 2015 could restore some of the references.  However I have a complain like this -
[image]

Clicking button Restore will have this error -

[image]

I don't think I have used a version of 1.0.3 of Newtonsoft.Json.dll directly.  I deleted the package folder and all project bin and obj folders.  The recompile still can not fix it.

What can be done to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you also delete the NuGet.Config file in the  packages folder? If you did it, Visual Studio will try to do the MSBuild package restore instead of  Automatic Package Restore.

> By default, the NuGet.Config file instructs NuGet to bypass adding
>   package binaries to source control. Automatic Package Restore will
>   honor this as long as you leave this file in place. Note that
>   NuGet.Config only has an effect when using Visual Studio to integrate
>   with Team Foundation Server (TFS).

You should also manually remove references in all your projects to the Nuget.targets file. The following article outlines in more details: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

If you still can't fix it, try to use the [Command-Line Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore)